# How can I install vscode-server in linux offline

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to install VScode remote-ssh extensions, but my remote host could not connect to the Internet,so there is no way to download software is needed.
So I got some error message like that:

```
SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+kf"
SSH Resolver called for host: kf
Setting up SSH remote "kf"
Using commit id "daf71423252a707b8e396e8afa8102b717f8213b" and quality "insider" for server
Install and start server if needed
> bash: no job control in this shell
> Installing...
> Downloading with wget
> ERROR: certificate common name “*.azurewebsites.net” doesn’t match requested host name “update.code.visualstudio.com”. To connect to update.code.visualstudio.com insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.
> 2b948abc-b874-4ef5-875a-a29370a5f844##25##
"install" terminal command done
Received install output: 2b948abc-b874-4ef5-875a-a29370a5f844##25##
Server download failed
Downloading VS Code Server failed. Please try again later.
```

How could I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

1. First get commit id
2. Download vscode server from url: `https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:${commit_id}/server-linux-x64/stable`
3. Upload the `vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz` to server
4. Unzip the downloaded `vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz` to `~/.vscode-server/bin/${commit_id}` without vscode-server-linux-x64 dir
5. Create `0` file under `~/.vscode-server/bin/${commit_id}`

```bash
commit_id=f06011ac164ae4dc8e753a3fe7f9549844d15e35

# Download url is: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:${commit_id}/server-linux-x64/stable
curl -sSL "https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:${commit_id}/server-linux-x64/stable" -o vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz

mkdir -p ~/.vscode-server/bin/${commit_id}
tar zxvf vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz -C ~/.vscode-server/bin/${commit_id} --strip 1
touch ~/.vscode-server/bin/${commit_id}/0
```

- or -

See this Gist [download-vs-code-server](https://gist.github.com/b01/0a16b6645ab7921b0910603dfb85e4fb) for a more complete shell script that will also get the latest released commit SHA (from GitHub) so you do not need to supply it yourself.

---

*[edited to add helpful comment in case comments disappear later:]*

You can replace `commit:<commit>` with `latest` to get the latest release build. Example: `https://update.code.visualstudio.com/latest/server-linux-x64/stable`. Respects indicated quality i.e, `stable`, `insider`. – [Doom5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4121010/doom5)

Comment: Thanks! One more question: how can I upgrade the extension when there is one available in the future?

Comment: Yeah but how can I get the latest ${commit_id} once there is an update? Btw, I created an issue regarding this, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3100.

Comment: when you connect to remote with vscode, open detail message, a commit id is in output message, eg:[14:25:33.213] Using commit id "5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a" and quality "stable" for server

Comment: @idailylife you can't connect to remote once there have a new version, because vscode will use new commit id to connect server which do not exist

Comment: You can replace `commit:<commit>` with `latest` to get the latest release build. Example: `https://update.code.visualstudio.com/latest/server-linux-x64/stable`. Respects indicated quality i.e, `stable`, `insider`.

Comment: Nice! I was having a problem doing this automatically through VS Code because of a proxy and this helped immensely. I turned this into a shell script and replaced the commit ID value with `$1`. Just call it with `get_server.sh {commit_id}`, which will make it easy to update when necessary.

Comment: FYI, the commit_id's match the commit hashes from releases here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases

Comment: what is the link for windows?

Comment: How many time I've come back to this life-saving answer...

Comment: @yekanchi Windows link is `https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:${commit_id}/server-win32-x64/stable` which downloads vscode-server.zip

Comment: There is also a chance that code will decide it wants the alpine download even when it's not musl (e.g. Amazon Linux) and the link was  `https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:${commit_id}/cli-alpine-x64/stable`

Comment: Solution with version number: `https://update.code.visualstudio.com/${version}/server-linux-x64/stable`.

Example: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.85.2/server-linux-x64/stable.

Get the commit id from archive: `tar -axf vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz vscode-server-linux-x64/product.json -O | grep '"commit":' | sed 's#\s*"commit":\s*"\([^"]\+\)".*#\1#')`.