# Is it possible to use vscode server for remote wsl in an offline installation?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When starting vscode from Ubuntu 20.04 using WSL2 using the remote WSL extension, vscode tries to fetch vscode server binaries from online.

Is it possible to install these binaries in an offline install where it does not try to download new binaries?

```
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (d2e414d9e4239a252d1ab117bd7067f125afd80a)
Downloading: 100%
Failed
--2020-10-30 11:04:23--  https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:d2e414d9e4239a252d1ab117bd7067f125afd80a/server-linux-x64/stable
Resolving update.code.visualstudio.com (update.code.visualstudio.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘update.code.visualstudio.com’
ERROR: Failed to download https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:d2e414d9e4239a252d1ab117bd7067f125afd80a/server-linux-x64/stable to /home/myuser/.vscode-server/bin/d2e414d9e4239a252d1ab117bd7067f125afd80a-1604073862.tar.gz
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install vscode-server in linux offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671520/how-can-i-install-vscode-server-in-linux-offline)