# VScode remote '_workbench.downloadResource' failed

Tags: visual-studio-code

[11:38:09.887] Got request to download on client for {"platform":"linux","arch":"x64","destFolder":"PATH/COMMITID"}

[11:38:09.887] Downloading VS Code server locally...

[11:38:30.909] Resolver error: Error: Running the contributed command: '_workbench.downloadResource' failed.

I tried to download it manually
https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:COMMITID/server-linux-x64/stable, but appeared "not found" message.

I remembered it can be downloaded as vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz before.

Comment: The download link works fine, what you need to do is replace the COMMITID word with an actual commit ID string. See here for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/56781109/465662

Comment: This answer solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/57601121/2374691

Comment: It depends on your internet... I met the same problem

Comment: My development environment is entirely offline, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56781109/3476780) was the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is the version of remote ssh.

Currently, the version is v0.65.1. Downgraded to v0.61.0 and it works.

[Ref](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/533)

Answer (score 0):

this issue is due to vscode server failed to download in the remote machine.
You can get it manually like wget https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/2aeda6b18e13c4f4f9edf6667158a6b8d408874b/vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
and extract to be a path like : ~/.vscode-server/bin/2aeda6b18e13c4f4f9edf6667158a6b8d408874b
notice that 2aeda6b18e13c4f4f9edf6667158a6b8d408874b is the commit id of vscode, you can get it from code --version on your client machine.

Answer (score 0):

rm .vscode file folde in windows, then Re-download remote development plugin in vscode; try again.