# Visual Studio Code Remote SSH no longer working "Waiting for server log"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

This just started happening today after I upgraded VSCode. It connects fine to one of my AWS machines, but not to one that had been working fine for a while. It's not related to my ssh keys, because even if I remove it, it still ends up with the same outcome.

Here is what I get in the output log when trying to remote-ssh:

```
[15:00:18.550] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 57103 "DEV" bash
[15:00:18.552] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:00:18.744] > key_load_public: invalid format
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:00:18.745] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[15:00:19.441] > warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha2-512)
[15:00:20.673] > 1b2d18264e08: running
[15:00:20.707] > Acquiring lock on /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c245083
> 06b151f30d/vscode-remote-lock.ubuntu.3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d   
[15:00:20.723] > Found existing installation at /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce
> 27b7b5c24508306b151f30d...
> Checking /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/.3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d.l
> og and /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/.3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d.pid
>  for a running server
[15:00:20.745] > Looking for server with pid: 1494
> Starting server with command... /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dc
> e27b7b5c24508306b151f30d/server.sh --start-server --host=127.0.0.1 --enable-remo
> te-auto-shutdown  --port=0  &> "/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/.3c4e3df9e89829dce27
> b7b5c24508306b151f30d.log" < /dev/null
> printenv:
>     SSH_CONNECTION=68.132.254.210 57105 172.31.46.222 22
>     LANG=C.UTF-8
>     XDG_SESSION_ID=6
>     USER=ubuntu
>     PWD=/home/ubuntu
>     HOME=/home/ubuntu
>     SSH_CLIENT=68.132.254.210 57105 22
>     MAIL=/var/mail/ubuntu
>     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     SHLVL=2
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server
>     LOGNAME=ubuntu
>     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
>     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
[15:00:20.745] > 
> :/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
> Spawned remote server: 2989
[15:00:20.753] > 
> Waiting for server log...
.......
[15:00:28.621] > Waiting for server log...
[15:00:28.655] > Waiting for server log...
[15:00:28.689] > Waiting for server log...
[15:00:28.723] >  
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,  
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057) 
> *
> 
[15:00:28.733] > 
> Server did not start successfully. Full server log at /home/ubuntu/.vscode-serve
> r/.3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d.log >>>
> <<< End of server log
> 1b2d18264e08: start
> exitCode==32==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==ubuntu==
> arch==x86_64==
> tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
> platform==linux==
[15:00:28.736] > 
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==7980==
> 1b2d18264e08: end
[15:00:28.736] Received install output: 
exitCode==32==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==x86_64==
tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==7980==
[15:00:28.742] Resolver error: Error: The VS Code Server failed to start
    at Function.ServerInstallError (c:\Users\Marc Zeitouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:64575)
    at c (c:\Users\Marc Zeitouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:58900)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Marc Zeitouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:63317)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\Marc Zeitouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:413984)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async c:\Users\Marc Zeitouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:294518
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Marc Zeitouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:405329)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\Marc Zeitouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:295639)
    at async c:\Users\Marc Zeitouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:127:110530
[15:00:28.748] ------
[15:00:29.311] "install" terminal command done
[15:00:29.311] Install terminal quit with output:
```

Comment: I want to know the answer to this too. I'll try to reproduce

Comment: I had this problem with a newly-updated Insiders build. Going back to Stable was the only thing that fixed it for me.

Comment: Note that there is an issue related to this in the latest version (1.86.0) of VSCode. My answer below addresses this specific issue.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue. On the remote system, I removed the /.vscode-server folder, which forces the vscode-server.tar.gz to be downloaded again, unzip the folder and extensions get transferred by scp.

```
rm -fr ~/.vscode-server/
```

If your remote device does not have access to internet, you can use this:
[Install VSCODE server offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671520/how-can-i-install-vscode-server-in-linux-offline)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. The solution that worked for me was reinstalling the VS Code server on the remote host. Below are the instructions:

All the operations are done on the local VS Code's command palette:

1. open the command palette
2. select "Remote-SSH: uninstall vscode server from host"
3. select the remote host that you can't connect to

Then, restart the VS Code and reconnect. The VS code server will be reinstalled on the remote host and now you should be able to connect to it.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was to update the vscode extensions:
-Remote-Containers
-Remote-SSH
-Remote-WSL

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. What fixed it for me was to kill the vscode server on the host:

1. `ctrl+shift+p` to open command palette.
2. Select "Remote-SSH: kill VS Code Server on Host..."
3. Select the host that you can't connect to.

Then, restart VS Code and reconnect.

Answer (score 3):

I hit this when running out of disk space (or quota). Try ssh-ing directly to the remote host and creating some new files (e.g., `tar zcvf ~/vscode-backup ~/.vscode-server`).

Comment: Or check your quota with `df -kh`

Answer (score 2):

**Update February 2024.**

VSCode version 1.86.0 has an issue with older distributions (on the remote server) not being supported anymore. The issue is [known](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203967).

Currently, a workaround is to revert to [VSCode 1.85](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85) (or have a separate installation of 1.85.0) and disable auto-updates for this installation until the issue is fixed.

Direct download links for VSCode 1.85. (from the GitHub Issues page linked above):

- [darwin](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/VSCode-darwin.zip)
- [darwin-arm64](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/VSCode-darwin-arm64.zip)
- [darwin-universal](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/VSCode-darwin-universal.zip)
- [linux-arm64](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/code-stable-arm64-1705560634.tar.gz)
- [linux-armhf](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/code-stable-armhf-1705559744.tar.gz)
- [linux-deb-arm64](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/code_1.85.2-1705560689_arm64.deb)
- [linux-deb-armhf](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/code_1.85.2-1705559800_armhf.deb)
- [linux-deb-x64](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/code_1.85.2-1705561292_amd64.deb)
- [linux-rpm-arm64](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/code-1.85.2-1705560776.el7.aarch64.rpm)
- [linux-rpm-armhf](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/code-1.85.2-1705559886.el7.armv7hl.rpm)
- [linux-rpm-x64](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/code-1.85.2-1705561377.el7.x86_64.rpm)
- [linux-snap-x64](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/code-stable-x64-1705562349.snap)
- [linux-x64](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/code-stable-x64-1705560028.tar.gz)
- [win32-arm64](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/VSCodeSetup-arm64-1.85.2.exe)
- [win32-arm64-archive](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/VSCode-win32-arm64-1.85.2.zip)
- [win32-arm64-user](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/VSCodeUserSetup-arm64-1.85.2.exe)
- [win32-x64](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/VSCodeSetup-x64-1.85.2.exe)
- [win32-x64-archive](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/VSCode-win32-x64-1.85.2.zip)
- [win32-x64-user](https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.85.2.exe)

Answer (score 2):

Temporary solution for **February 2024**:

Revert to VSCode 1.85 and disable auto-updates for this installation until the issue is fixed.

To downgrade with apt, you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install code=1.85.2*
```

And then hold the version with:

```
sudo apt-mark hold code
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, checking the log file inside ~/.vscode-server on host I could find that libatomic.so.1 was missing.
Install using:

```
apt install libatomic1
```

If you find any other lib missing, I suggest you use "apt-file search " and install every missing package you get from the log.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue

After

```
rm -fr ~/.vscode-server/
```

from remote side, than clear the disconnect server config in SSH configuration file(.ssh/cinfig), restart vscode and add server config in setting.

it works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check for log file in `~/.vscode-server/.<vs-code-process-id-file-name>.log`
There might be a missing package in your server which would be required after updating extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the latest version of vscode when I wanted to connect to a remote server with CentOS 7.0.  Downgrading VSCode to version 1.72.2 resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with VS Code release 1.86, the minimum requirements for the build toolchain of the remote server were raised. The prebuilt servers distributed by VS Code are compatible with Linux distributions based on glibc 2.28 or later, for example, Debian 10, RHEL 8, Ubuntu 20.04.

Refer for more details -

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/faq#_can-i-run-vs-code-server-on-older-linux-distributions

Solution -

Downgrade VS Code to 1.85 and disable auto updates

Or

Use portable version of VS Code