# How does VS Code handle file synchronization in a remote container?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm using VS Code Remote Container and I usually **attach to an existing container** in Kuberentes. I can edit files remotely but I'm not sure how VS Code caches the remote files/folders? Does it create any additional files or volumes locally in order to keep the cached folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code handle remotes features with the **VS Code Server**. This is a Microsoft binary that interact with your local VS Code through an exposed port:

[image: VS Code Interactions]
From: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers

That's why when you're peering for the first time your VS Code with your K8S container, VS Code install **VS Code Server** binary inside your container, wich open a specific port for the *VS Code full-feature communication* with your client. I was not able to find any source for the server, however you can reverse-engineering this process to get the binary server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57601121/9414882