# How to solve visual studio code ssh-remote when it shows the following xhr failed

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, raspberry-pi3, visual-studio-code-server

After i click the remote-ssh in visual studio code and try to connect my raspberry server this is the following error it pop up.
'can't connect to 192.168.50.13 : XHR failed'.

In other to solve this problem i have tried the following ways.

1. Access to raspberry pi server by using vnc viewer and open the cmd file. Input the following codes.

"cd ~"   and then i type   "rm -rf .vscode- server"

"cd../"   and then i type   "rm -rf .vscode- server"

"cd../" twice   and then i type   "rm -rf .vscode- server"

2. Download the server by using commit id. step by step from following link.
   [How can I install vscode-server in linux offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671520/how-can-i-install-vscode-server-in-linux-offline)

But both of these steps couldn't able to solve my problem. Please let me knows how to solve this problem. Thank you!